# Find dataframe average values for each timestamp on different days

Tags: python, pandas

Helo everyone,

I'm trying to find the average of my `powerAC` dataframe (5min interval) for each day, so I have 1 year of data and for the whole period I would like to know what was the average value at 09:05, 09:10, 09:15, for example, and so on. Here is an example:

[image]

And I would like my output to be as follows:

[image]

The closer I got to what I want was:

```
minute = pd.to_timedelta(powerAC.index.minute, unit='m')
powerAC.astype(float).groupby(minute).mean()
```

tried with `powerAC.index.hour` also but still doesn't provide me with my desired output. I saw many solution in here but they were all with hourly average or 5 minute average using `.resample`. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
hhmm = pd.to_datetime(powerAC.index).strftime('%H:%M')
powerAC.astype(float).groupby(hhmm).mean()
```

If you want timedelta, you can do:

```
datetime = pd.to_datetime(powerAC.index)
hhmm = datetime - datetime.floor('D')

powerAC.astype(float).groupby(hhmm).mean()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly fine as well!!

Answer (score 1):

Check

```
minute = powerAC.index.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is exactly what I was looking for!!